# Unresolved reference DaggerApplicationComponent when add usecase in ViewModel

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am developing in Android of MVVM with Clean Architecture, and the sample viewModel is like the following:

```
class TestViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private var test1UseCase: Test1UseCase,
    private var test21UseCase: Test21UseCase,
    private var test3UseCase: Test3UseCase
)
```

it works fine. But when I try to add the `Test4UseCase`, it shows **Unresolved reference DaggerApplicationComponent**.

I already implement the following in app.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
```

The dagger version is `dagger2Version = '2.28'`

before adding the new UseCase, the code works fine. The error only happened when adding the new UseCase.

Does it has an upper limit of usecase ? Did I miss something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share you setup Dagger Component and your build.gradle?

Comment: Dagger should have given you an error message (probably `[Dagger/MissingBinding]`).  Can you post that error?

Comment: @Nitrodon. No, it does not show other Missing binding error. the error happened seems not because of missing binding.